# How to get all the href nodeValue based on rel='manifest' in <link>

Tags: javascript, xml, domparser

I am new to XML parsing and getting data from XML and I am trying to get the array of `href` links from the XML which I am getting from API response.

One of the `res` value is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <manifests
        xmlns="http://www.xyz.ca/ws/manifest-v8">
        <link rel="manifest" href="link1" media-type="application/vnd.cpc.manifest-v8+xml"/>
        <link rel="artifact" href="artifact1" media-type="application/vnd.cpc.manifest-v8+xml"/>
        <link rel="manifest" href="link2" media-type="application/vnd.cpc.manifest-v8+xml"/>
    </manifests>
```

and I am parsing `res` using DOMParser() as

```
const document =  new DOMParser().parseFromString(res, 'application/xml');
 console.log((document.querySelectorAll("link[rel='manifest']")).length);
 console.log(document.querySelectorAll("link[rel='manifest']")[0].attributes['href'].nodeValue);
```

I want the array using `querySelectorAll` method which will give all the `nodeValues` of `href` with `<link rel="manifest">`.

For example, if the `res` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <manifests
        xmlns="http://www.xyz.ca/ws/manifest-v8">
        <link rel="manifest" href="link1" media-type="application/vnd.cpc.manifest-v8+xml"/>
        <link rel="artifact" href="artifact1" media-type="application/vnd.cpc.manifest-v8+xml"/>
        <link rel="manifest" href="link2" media-type="application/vnd.cpc.manifest-v8+xml"/>
    </manifests>
```

then the  `querySelectorAll` should return `["link1","link2"]`

I tried `document.querySelectorAll("link[rel='manifest']"))` but it gives the array of `<link>`.
I also tried  `document.querySelectorAll("link[rel='manifest']")[0].attributes['href'].nodeValue` but it only gives `link1`.

How can I get all the nodeValues as array using querySelectorAll instead of passing index and getting one nodeValue at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be other ways to do this, but one way would be to turn your `NodeList` from `querySelectorAll` to an `array` then use `map` to get the properties you are interested in into a new array.

e.g.

```
let hrefs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("link[rel='manifest']")).map(x => x.attributes['href'].nodeValue)
```

What this does is:

create an array from `document.querySelectorAll("link[rel='manifest']")`

then map that array selecting the property you want from each element `x => x.attributes['href'].nodeValue` (where `x` is each element in the array we created).

Comment: I believe you can call `.map()` directly on the node list returned from `.querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - hmm I don't think so, NodeList doesn't implement map - i.e. Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).map is not a function

Comment: Ah, well since it does implement `.forEach()` these days, I thought `.map()` would work too.

Comment: @ScottMarcus  Ah I see what you mean...The issue is that NodeLists don’t share the Array prototype - so whilst it has forEach it doesn't support array methods.